# Array out of bounds exception on simple check box program

Tags: arrays

I have 4 checkboxes, when selected they should concatenate onto a single string displayed on a Jlabel.  It was working before sort-of, not sure whatI did to break it, now I get array exception out of bounds errors.  This is the update() method being run whenever a checkbox is interacted with.

http://pastebin.com/tbSpx7jA

It's been answered thanks all, just messed up my initial array declaration.

Comment: put your code here, not on an external site.  And only put what is germane to your issue.

Comment: also, it would improve the quality of this question if you explained what you had already done to try to solve the problem

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're iterating to an index that does not exist:

```
for (int j = 0; j <= oslist2.length; j++)
```

should be

```
for (int j = 0; j < oslist2.length; j++)
```

Java array indexes are (0, 1, 2... length-1)

You also have

```
oslist2[3]="";
```

which means, you should make the array bigger, or don't use that index.
This should work:

```
String[] oslist2 = new String[4];
```

Comment: Hmm It still throws the same error, arrayindexoutofboundsexception.  Odd.  It compiles ok just breaks whenever I click a box.

Comment: Thanks mate, just realized that as well.  Can't believe I overlooked that simple mistake oops